# Locking a cell in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to lock a cell in VBA Excel. I read the previous answers and used them. but the cell does not lock.!!!!
this is my code:

```
Number = Range("A1")
If Number < 5 Then
    Cells(1, 1).Locked = True
Else
    Cells(1, 1).Locked = False
End If
```

After the subroutine runs the `cells(1,1)` is not protected.

Answer (score 0):

Locked cell become protected when you switch protection for the worksheet. You need to add

```
Cells(1, 1).Worksheet.Protect
```

That makes all locked cells protected (see [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836172.aspx)).

P.S. By default all the cells [are locked](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Lock-cells-in-a-worksheet-b2f833bd-9db5-48a4-9ec0-8e451ac27c3a)